# Need help returning a higher value if value is < 400

Tags: javascript

I've tried so many things trying to make this work.  I have a function that returns the value of Labor price for a product.  I need the minimum value to return as 400.  If it's over 400, I need for it to be the value * 0.22%.  This is what I have so far...

```
 calculatelabor = function(e) {
           return e * 0.22 
},
```

Comment: You'll need to use an `if` statement to check if the value is over 400 or not. Tutorial here: [Conditional branching](https://javascript.info/ifelse)

Comment: Multiplying by `0.22` gives `22%`, not `0.22%`

Comment: you need to multiply the value with  `0.0022` to get `0.22%` and also check if the value is greater than 400. For example `if(e > 400)`

Comment: Given the range of interpretations in the answers, I'd suggest you add a little more detail about what you want from this calculation.

Comment: I've tried this as well... ```calculatelabor = function(e) {
   if (e > 400) {
        return e * 0.22;
    }
 else if (e < 400) {
        return e * 0.80;
    }        
},```

Comment: try this: `calculatelabor = function(e) { return Math.max(400, e * 0.0022); };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
calculatelabor = function(e) {
           return e * 0.22 < 400? 400 : e * 0.22;
}
```

Comment: I have tried so many things, I'm still learning javascript and this was soo helpful!  Thank you a million @alpdeniz!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's a basic `if` conditional construct:

```js
 
 
 function calculatelabor(e) {
  var labor = e * 0.22;
  return labor < 400 ? 400 : labor; 
}

console.log(calculatelabor(300));
console.log(calculatelabor(40000));
```

Comment: From the question, I suppose the minimum value (labor price) to be returned in 400 . So the  (e * 0.22) should be calculated first and if its less than 400, 400 should be returned.   ie., something like Math.max(400, e*0.22);

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
calculatelabor = function(e) {
    return e <= 400 ? 400 : e + e * 0.22 / 100
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it returned labor at Labor
$1,498.29   when the material price was $1495.00    Labor should be minimum of 400 and if over 400 should be material price * 22%

Answer (score 2):

```js
const calculate = (value) => {
  return value > 400 ? 400*0.22 : 400; 
}

console.log(calculate(300))
console.log(calculate(500))
```